# cassandra tablehistogram shows high sstables

Tags: cassandra

The table has 24 sstables with size tiered compaction, when I run nodetool tablehistograms I see 99% percentile of the queries are showing up 24 as the number of sstables. But the read latency is very low, my understanding from the tableshistograms's sstable column is - it shows how many sstables were read to complete the query. If so reading 24 sstables should take sometime, at least maybe couple of seconds. Am I missing something here? Does checking against index/bloom filters count towards sstable counter as well?

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%            24.00             17.08          17436.92               310                 6
75%            24.00             24.60          20924.30               446                 6
95%            24.00             42.51          62479.63               770                10
98%            24.00             51.01          74975.55              1597                17
99%            24.00             61.21          74975.55              3311                24
Min            18.00              2.30           4866.32                87                 0
Max            24.00            943.13          89970.66            545791             17084
```

Answer (score 1):

This value keeps on changing with set of queries running on particular table .

Here , size of records are very less 3311 bytes and table consists  of very few columns .

Are you selecting all records while running  the query  or you have single partition only .
Thats why , your query reads all stables.